# Python subclassing issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, subclass

I'm having an issue with a python subclass :

I have my own class, Player which extends a MediaPlayer class defined in an external module.
MediaPlayer extends _Ctype and implements the `__new__` method.

Below is the code of my class :

```
import vlc
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject
from core import Media

class Player(vlc.MediaPlayer, QObject):
    def __new__(cls,  *args):
        return super(Player, cls).__new__(cls, *args)

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(Player, self).__init__(self, None)

    def setMedia(self,  location=None):
        print(self)
        media = Media.Media(location)
        print("Player.setMedia")
        self.set_media(media)
```

And when I call

```
player.setMedia([file_path]) #player is supposed to be an instance of the Player class
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'MediaPlayer' object has no attribute 'setMedia'
```

The issue seems to be that when I instanciate the Player class it returns a MediaPlayer instance and therefore I can't use the setMedia method.

So I was wondering if any of you had any inkling why that issue occured and how to solve it.

Thank you for reading my post so far.

I use Python 3.4.2 64bit on Windows 8.1 64bit.

Comment: You wrote `__new` instead of `__new__`.

Comment: @BrenBarn You wrote `comment` instead of `answer`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't entirely understand the ctypes code of the `vlc` module, but it sure looks like it doesn't properly support inheritance. The return value of `MediaPlayer.__new__` is always an instance of `MediaPlayer`, rather than an instance of the type that gets passed in as the `cls` arg. I imagine this is a bug.

I'm not sure if you can work around this directly. One possible solution is to try fixing up the class of the object you get back in `__new__`:

```
def __new__(cls,  *args):
    self = super(Player, cls).__new__(cls, *args)
    self.__class__ = cls
    return self
```

I don't know if this will work correctly (or at all). The `__class__` attribute is not always writable in objects built in C code, and even if it can be written to, it might break things.

A further issue is that the second base type, `QObject`, does not get its `__new__` method called by `MediaPlayer.__new__`. If `QObject` does anything special there, the instance you get after changing the `__class__` variable may still not be in a sane state. Usually you need all of your base classes to support cooperative multiple inheritance if you're going to do anything complicated with more than one base (mixins are perhaps an exception), but in this case you have at least one base that doesn't even support single inheritance properly.

Another, perhaps more foolproof solution would be to abandon inheritance (at least for the `MediaPlayer` part of your `Player`), and just create a reference to a `MediaPlayer` instance in `__init__`:

```
class Player(QObject):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)                  # pass args to QObject?
        self.media_player = MediaPlayer(*args)   # and to MediaPlayer as well?
    def setMedia(self,  location=None):
        print(self)
        media = Media.Media(location)
        print("Player.setMedia")
        self.media_player.set_media(media)
```

If you're calling `MediaPlayer` methods on a `Player` instance in other code, you may need to proxy the relevant methods.

Comment: Sadly, your first solution didn't work. `self.__class__ = cls` returns a TypeError because the object layouts differ. So I abandonned inheritance but instead of proxying the methods I implemented the `__call__` function to return a MediaPlayer object and it does exactly what I wanted.